# Problem with the MATLAB function 'uihtml'

Tags: python, matlab, dictionary, user-interface, qgis

I'm working on my GUI with MATLAB app designer, I wanted to make an interactive map to my GUI, I made a HTML map with a plugin with the software QGIS, that made the map with some java and CSS files as well in the folder of it.

When I open the HTML file of the map via chrome its works fine I see all the layers of the map I made and its interactive with search and measuring tool.

But when I try to open it via MATLAB with the 'uihtml' function i get it to be opened but all I see is the layers I made of the data I implemented in the map it self but without the most important layer the map itself.

What do I miss because I dont get not errors to this kinda of a problem.
This is what I get when I open the file via chrome:
[image]

This is what I get when I open it with the `uihtml` function in MATLAB:
[image]

I try to use the geo functions of matlab to make what I want in my GUI but its make my code more complicated and its not really use full because my GUI works on a different coordinates of the map then what MATLAB is working (WGS).

I tried to make a new map (made 4) all didn't work.

The HTML file is in a folder and the other files are in semi-folders, I tried to export all of them to be in one folder that didn't work either.

I tried to open it via python (I don't really know python) but that also didn't work...